# Canonical question for ArrayIndexOutOfBounds questions

Tags: discussion, canonical

I was just looking at this question here: [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178847/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-200) when I happened to notice it's rather interesting "Related" section:

[image]

The abundance of questions similar to this doesn't really seem constructive for the site. So my question is: Is there—or should there be—a canonical question that these can be linked to? I'm thinking of something similar to how most questions about NullPointerExceptions get marked as duplicates of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/24100776#24100776)

I've been doing a little searching but so far I haven't found any that would be good candidates. The answers are all too specific to the situation in the question itself.

Comment: the problem is similar to the NPE problem: it can be caused by a large number of different things. I don't think linking to a canonical would really help unless a single answer (or set of answers) can solve the problem for the majority of cases. If all you're going to do is explain how to debug the error, maybe a more general "how to debug java" canonical would be more appropriate.

Comment: There should be one.  Go ask it.  Provide a great answer that hits all the highlights of all the best of the dupes.  Then start voting to close of this canonical.

Comment: [Found the canonical](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5554781/4639281). (By Jon Skeet of course)

Comment: Nice find @TinyGiant. Should that be added as an answer?

Comment: Now if only you had 3000 reputation points, you would have [416 duplicates to close](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception%22+closed%3Ano) which would only take you approximately 9.25 days.

Comment: @TinyGiant:  That looks fine for a canonical, although there should be some additional information about the enhanced-for statement (Skeet mentions it but he doesn't really elaborate on it).  It does require a bit of clean-up, though.

Comment: The user [Jarrod Roberson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/177800/jarrod-roberson) also created a canonical Q&A for this problem, but it got closed (I casted a close vote with the already mentioned question, before it was clear what he tried to achieve there) and downvoted, so he deleted it. Maybe he (or someone else) can undelete it, so it can be used again, since the answer was more elaborated than the ones in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it.

Comment: @TinyGiant, indeed, Skeet's answer covers many cases, but doesn't mention things like using iterators without enhanced `for` loops.

Comment: It may make sense to add that Q&A to the [java FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) in the debugging section.

Comment: Does it make sense to add it to the FAQ now, or does it require more polishing up before doing so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@TinyGiant found this canonical for questions of this nature: [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it/5554781#5554781)

However, this should be used judiciously. It doesn't amount to a lot more than "Don't use array indices that don't exist". It could be used for the questions where they used `<=` instead of `<` in a for loop, since that is really the only example of a potential issue it gives, but these exceptions could be caused by any number of other things.

Before marking a question as a dupe of this canonical, make sure it doesn't warrant an MCVE and debugging answer.

EDIT:
User assyilias has added this canonical to the list of Java FAQs:
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607018/204

Comment: Yup, that makes a lot of sense to me. While the immediate cause of this error is very often the same, my answer really only addresses one "source level" cause.

Comment: @TinyGiant: If you're calling an API that doesn't perform argument validation, you could easily end up seeing it for things which aren't array accesses as far as you're concerned, but end up as array accesses. I know that's not a great example... I'm just nervous of my answer as-is being seen as canonical without thinking being involved. But yes, I'm happy to edit the answer as cases come up.

Comment: @Jon skeet that answer was at 40 upvotes before I linked it here when it had been visible for 1655 days, averaging an upvote every 41.375 days. Since then it has gotten 58 upvotes and has been visible for an additional 319 days, averaging an upvote every 5.5 days. It also currently has 303 linked questions. Basically it has grossed almost 1.5 times as many votes in the past year as it did in the previous 4.5 years on the site. A bit of useless trivia there, but I felt like sharing it.