# Is this an acceptable canonical question and answer for a common Java exception?

Tags: discussion, canonical, dupehammer

I believe this is related to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316754/canonical-question-needed-javas-infamous-arraylistint-n), but it appears that [a question and answer have been proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568261/how-to-avoid-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception) as a canonical resource for `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The asker of this question has started using their gold badge duplicate closure capabilities to close many questions as a duplicate of this.

We have started to receive a series of complaints about this, but I do know that a call had been put out for such a canonical question. For those active in this area, is this an acceptable question and do you agree with this user's closure of the following questions as duplicates of this?

- [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using the ArrayList's iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700717/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-when-iterating-through-an-arraylist)
- [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)
- [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using ListAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659577/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-when-using-listadapter)
- [Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null BUT why is there no stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582370/java-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-null-but-why-is-there-no-stack-trace)
- [ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280092/arraylist-indexoutofboundsexception-java)
- [Java empty String split ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606215/java-empty-string-split-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)
- [How to Find Union of Two String Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394824/how-to-find-union-of-two-string-arrays)
- [How to avoid getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908606/how-to-avoid-getting-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

A total of [over 100 questions have been closed as a duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/32568261?lq=1), most in the last few days. Does the Java community agree with this?

Comment: As someone without significant Java experience, I can't see any reason why the top two questions in your list are inferior to the "canonical".

Comment: @TZHX - Given that they're more highly voted and also significantly older than the target, I wondered if I was missing something.

Comment: I think the second one has a better q&a pair in general, the first one probably a bit of extra google-juice for having "ArrayList" in the slug. Compared to the target, both lack obnoxious formatting and what (I feel) is OTT code sample.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255738/duplicate-closing-rampage

Comment: Can you lock that post as *dispute --currently under meta discussion*? Just to prevent meta effect. (If it is not eligible, then sry for this comment. Ty)

Comment: @Bhar What activity on the question since this meta post do you feel has been inappropriate?

Comment: @TZHX Nothing as far as now. Thinking of the future. When it goes to the CB after it becomes a HMP...; There was a question earlier which received 70 or so downvotes deleted thrice undeleted thrice, etc, etc. because of meta effect (That was a completely different case though).

Comment: @Bhar As of now, it's had one vote in each direction, a comment about this meta post, and an edit to remove a tag that was completely irrelevant to the question. I don't think pre-emptive locks to protect questions from the meta effect is a healthy pattern.

Comment: @TZHX Fair enough. Brad would know it better than me, That's why I left a comment with an apology at the end (like an Anticipatory Bail Order). If you feel the comment is not constructive, please do inform me. I will be more than happy to delete all of those. Ty.

Comment: @Bhar I don't think it's not constructive, this is a *discussion*. I responded to your point because I disagree with it and I'm egotistical enough to believe other people could agree with me, not because I don't think it's worth bringing up. :)

Comment: @TZHX Ah, Ok. I understand. Thanks for the discussion anyway. I did learn a thing or two, which certainly will be helpful for me.

Comment: I can't help think that this has something to do with the specific user.  Yes, he's opinionated and bored and isn't afraid to use his gold badge privileges.  If you can't sort it out from taking this off line one-on-one and pointing out that he's causing too much friction, and you don't want to throw him in the slammer, then just leave it up to the [java] community to sort out.  Everybody is entitled to vote to re-open.

Comment: @HansPassant:  I'm actually glad this was brought to the larger community's attention since I don't really watch the tag like a hawk at every waking moment, but I feel like I need to know when something like this happens.  Besides, Brad admits as much in this question:  he's not sure if this is something that's acceptable as a canonical, so asking the larger community is the right choice.

Comment: That banner is seriously annoying.  Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315643/are-broad-unspecific-questions-about-entire-topic-areas-preferred-over-specific/315675#315675

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Is his Q&A technically correct and are fit for being canonical? Is it okay for him to close many questions as dupes of his own? Are those closed questions really dupes of his? Judging by the discussion up to this point, I don't think that addressing the Java community specifically serves much purpose.

Answer (score 26):

I'm uncomfortable with this, *especially* considering that [this particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554734/1079354) has been the one I've been using as the canonical for this particular problem.

The aforementioned question above has all of the information available in that answer - albeit in a slightly less organized form - but the information is *still* all there.  Creating another question and answer to address it doesn't seem to solve a problem, but yet creates [another standard](https://xkcd.com/927/) for us to follow.

I think the main point I take umbrage with is that this wasn't exactly discussed.  It was just *implemented* without really getting input.  But I can take my curmudgeon blanket elsewhere on that one.

Ultimately, no.  I'm not liking that question and answer as a canonical.  The one I've linked to at the top of this answer feels better since it provides the same information in it.

If we're going to go into cleanup mode on this, it may be worth looking at questions which *were* closed as a dupe but *very clearly are not*, with this question [being a case in point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582370/java-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-null-but-why-is-there-no-stack-trace).  Remember:  just because it *has* that exception doesn't mean that it's the same question.  More than 10 seconds should be taken to look and see if the question is actually asking the same thing.

<sup>By the way:  my question *might* be related, but this one is more or less forcing the conversation rather than facilitating it.</sup>

Comment: I was using the same one as you to close those questions...  I think a Meta post would have been in order before going on the dupe-closing hunt.

Comment: This is the big sticking point for me: "just because it has that exception doesn't mean that it's the same question." It is frustrating that the original dupehammer-er ignored me at first when I pointed that out (even using your exact example), and eventually disagreed when I called it abusive of mod tools. But I do appreciate the community (and moderator) response on this.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the duplicate links have been reversed and the discussed canonical is now a duplicate of the one we used before.

Comment: @Tunaki:  Yeah, I took a minor stab at fixing one or two of those.  I don't have the luxury of time but later I plan on perusing the list and making sure that the ones that are closed *should* be as a duplicate.

Comment: Btw Jarrod wrote the same canonical Q&A several months ago and I flagged it as a duplicate of the one mentioned in this answer. This resulted in a small discussion with him and me where he explains why he thinks that his question is better in some points. He later deleted that Q&A, but maybe a 10k+ user can still find it to extract this discussion and his reasons to get more background information.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer of the [proposed canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568261/how-to-avoid-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception) is -IMO- a low quality answer that shouldn't be used as a canonical answer to this problem. Here is why :

1. The accepted answer provides **really bad** programming advice specially in the section:

> "How to avoid the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?
>
> When accessing directly by index"

<sub>Using a default value when index is out-of-bounds may work for some very particular use-cases, but the general way to avoid such exception is to test that the index is in range **before** using it.</sub>

2. All samples presenting various way to iterate over an array are mainly noise.
3. The "summary" is a bunch of opinion based statements mainly unrelated to the question.

IMHO,  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it) is far more readable, concise, correct and should be the cannonical question for this problem.

Answer (score 7):

Putting my annoyances over the dupehammering aside... There is an [existing meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308221/canonical-question-for-arrayindexoutofbounds-questions?rq=1) about creating a canonical ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException question. It looks like the consensus was that [this question was the best fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it) (same one that Makoto mentioned).

The answer in the [new proposed canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568261/how-to-avoid-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception) is nicely organized answer but why isn't that answer simply added to the question that already seems to be the generally agreed upon canonical? That's where the answer should be in my opinion, add it as answer to [the question that already seems like a great fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it). And if a dupehammer must be swung then the dupes should point to that existing question.

Comment: For frig's sake, I even *commented* on that.  Why couldn't I find it now??  Good find.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/20940980) is probably why.  Simple canonical question followed by wall-of-text encyclopedic answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey just to clarify, you're saying the wall-of-text is bad in that situation? It seems like the a logical way to format a vague, canonical answer. It goes over what, why, where, edge cases, avoidance, debugging. Those seem like good things to discuss. Or are you just saying it should be MUCH shorter?

Comment: Nevermind, you've answered my question in the related link you posted in your other comment