# Should the canonical answer for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException be generalized?

Tags: discussion, canonical

There is a canonical answer for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in Java: [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` **is-a** `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (meaning that it is actually a subclass). The associated tag is [indexoutofboundsexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexoutofboundsexception).

However, the current question and answer focus specifically on the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that is thrown when really using an *array*. The equally common case where someone writes

```
for (int i=0; i<=list.size(); i++) { ... }
```

is not covered there.

Of course, one could argue that this is nearly a syntactical detail, and everybody should be able to recognize the pattern. But one *has* to assume that *exactly* the people who ask about an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` are absolute beginners. Closing their questions as a duplicate might cause them to respond with something along the lines of *"I'm not using an array, so this does not help me!!!111"*. There *are* questions about `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, and people obviously did not find the matching answer or recognize the pattern (namely, that `<=` vs `<` is the crucial point here)

Should the current canonical Q/A be generalized to cover `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` **and** `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

(It would have to be done carefully, of course. Trying to squeeze too much information into the Q/A may be confusing. For example, it should try to *not* mention the exception inheritance hierarchy etc., because that's distracting and not relevant for the people who are asking this sort of question)

The alternative would be to close questions about `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as a duplicate, linking to the canonical in its current form, and mentioning (e.g. in a comment) that the fix is the same: "Just change `<=` to `<`".

---

(Note: The canonical Q/A for `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` has also been discussed in [Is this an acceptable canonical question and answer for a common Java exception?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/is-this-an-acceptable-canonical-question-and-answer-for-a-common-java-exception) , but this did not focus on generalizing it)