# Please help me improve my canonical post about dynamic evaluation in pandas

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, canonical

School's out for Christmas, and I recently found myself with a bit of spare time, so I wanted to find a better way to contribute here.

One of the primary tags I contribute to is the [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) tag. If you are familiar with this tag, you will know there is a serious issue with duplicate questions being asked (and answered) on a daily basis. Some of us are aware this problem has been going out of hand, and have actively been encouraging other users to vote and close such questions. However, the challenge here is that a lot of questions are badly written with unsearchable titles, so it is only natural users would rather spend 3 minutes to re-type the answer than spend 5 minutes to find the duplicate.

We recognised that many questions pertaining to an API, or family of APIs usually have the same, or similar answers (with minor variations) and can be closed as a duplicate of a single parent post that is easily searchable.

Some of us have taken the onus to churn out some solid canonicals to address the lack of searchable duplicates on the site. There are already a few good posts out there, including one on [pivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe), one on [merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) (disclaimer: by me), and one more on [concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620538/what-are-the-levels-keys-and-names-arguments-for-in-pandas-concat-functio).

Very recently (yesterday), I published a canonical on dynamically evaluating expressions in pandas (similar to numexpr with numpy). The post is

[Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval(), df.eval(), and df.query()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval-df-eval-and-df-query)

Dynamic evaluation in pandas is done by a small family of three functions that are very closely related to each other and share many common properties and arguments. However, many of the arguments are not very well documented, or their usage was not fully understood. My goal was to shed some light on these lesser known features using some clear and easy to understand examples in the hope that users would better understand and come to appreciate the power of this API. Further, many of the features and arguments do not make sense unless discussed in the context of other features. This is also why the post is somewhat long.

I have noticed the post has not been nearly as well received as the other canonicals, having received more downvotes than upvotes. I believe the post is technically sound, but technical soundness (or lack thereof) need not be the only reason for downvotes. I would like to take some time to understand where I have gone wrong with this post, how I could better frame the question, and rectify any mistakes in this, and future posts. How can I improve the structure and layout of this post to make it more helpful to future visitors?

Would appreciate your advice on this.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @coldspeed I've brought our discussion over here - from main. I think they're better off being hard linked. Either in the comments or in the question, than closed as dupes. It will cause issues. It already has been raising a lot of flags and if the other meta post is anything to go by, we're better off not marking them as dupes, but hard linking instead.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. The effort you've put into that post is amazing and I applaud that.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thank you very much. My main goal is to make content more easily searchable and accessible to users on this site. I only have good intentions in mind. Getting views and upvotes is always going to be a part of it, but as long as it is doing good to the site, I wonder if it is really that big an issue. However, I understand my actions have resulted in increased work for you and the other moderators, and I apologise for that. I will do my best to exercise better judgement when wielding my dupe hammer privilege in future.

Comment: @coldspeed you have nothing to apologise for. You're clearly trying to help the site and you are a prolific contributor. I wouldn't want to suppress that. It's just managing the prefered way to go about achieving all our objectives - a great site.

Comment: As a previously active user of the tag I think they are good posts. Especially the merge one. We definitely need more up to date, clearly written canonicals like these. It may raise some eyebrows when you are the one closing other questions right after writing the targets but it is not a big issue really. As the time passes I am sure the community will accept these.

Comment: @ayhan Thank you, so great to see you back here after such a long time, and I hope you can take a little time to answer a few every now and then... our tag is seriously hurting for good contributors like you and Ami :)

Comment: I know nothing of Python, but perhaps you could make the code in the question a MCVE and then have the answer show a solution based on that?

Comment: @Lundin I had a feeling that might be a possible issue... I am hoping [this edit of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53779986/3) addresses that.

Comment: @coldspeed It's not an issue, just a way to improve the post further, if the reader can copy/paste and try it out themselves.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not just addressing this specific post, but your trend to write canonicals of late and marking other posts as duplicates of your canonical post.

I applaud your efforts with these latest posts and in general on the site. However I'd point to this meta post:

[Is this an acceptable canonical question and answer for a common Java exception?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/is-this-an-acceptable-canonical-question-and-answer-for-a-common-java-exception)

The same thing is happening in your activity of late. There's a lot of flags being raised with posts you're hammering as duplicates of your own posts. We can't always have a canonical to cover every use case. It's not a tutorial site, but a question and answer site. So all those other more specific questions are useful for people to search on. Leading back to a broader duplicate is not always helpful.

I'd recommend hard linking the posts instead of marking them as duplicates. By hard linking - linking your posts as "related" in the comments, or adding the similar posts to the body of your question as related.

Comment: I wrote this answer, as it was under discussion by the mods, due to flags being raised. This is a way to get the message across and also allow the community to weigh in, without creating a separate meta discussion.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate the advice. I will stop marking as duplicate, and start hard linking instead—that's not an issue for me at all. I only want the content to be as accessible to users as possible, and in my mind marking as duplicate seemed like the most appropriate way to do so. In retrospect, I probably should have sought advice on meta, instead of only consulting a couple of other tag experts (as I did), so my apologies for that.

Comment: OTOH, if this is the cause of all the downvotes I have been receiving of late, I would implore users to remember to vote on the merits of the post, not because they disagree with the user's actions... that's what meta is for, and I am always open to respectful and meaningful discourse :)

Comment: @coldspeed stop apologising :) We couldn't function without people like you. Yeh downvotes are difficult. I help set up Pets when it was first launched. I was the most prolific user. I was doing similar things to you - trying to write canonical posts and get out questions to cover things to help make things searchable. It ended up with some of my posts being downvoted, as people viewed me as being too controlling and taking over the site. I suspect it's a little like that. Though I can't speak categorically for why people vote the way they do or what they think.

Comment: In your case, the site here is huge, if you don't close to many as dupes, I think you will find the reception easier.

Comment: Fair enough, let me reopen some of the older ones...

Comment: @coldspeed make sure you put a link to your canonical in the comments as related.  or track them some way.

Comment: Just un-hammered a large number of old, highly upvoted questions and instead added a comment on the question linking to my canonical. I hope this is better!

Comment: This is a good remark, I used to do the same. But when dupe hammering, we shouldn't use our own posts as dupe targets. So there's two ways to deal with duplicates when you know you have written a canonical post about it: either make your own post community wiki, after which you can dupe hammer away, no longer partial. Or alternatively, just post a comment "possible duplicate of <link>", then let other users make the call to close.

Comment: But @coldspeed I wouldn't go and unhammer posts, it will likely do more harm than you being partial, as you probably closed them for a good reason. What's done is done. If they shouldn't have been closed, others can vote to re-open.  Just mind this in the future and it should be enough.

Answer (score 9):

After a while lurking in the `python` tag, we tend to see everything as duplicates/composite duplicates, but let's not push it too far or we can close most of the questions here.

Reserve duplicate (including canonical) closure to either:

- too broad/poor questions that need to be closed somehow before someone answers the same thing over and over (since it's too broad, why not directing OP to a canonical duplicate. Some may object that it's abusing the hammering already.
- exact duplicates (I know, obvious)

This remains a Q&A site, I know there has been abuse with high-rep users answering obvious dupes (who hasn't already?) and I personally try to fight this, but let's not abuse in the other direction.

I'm sorry about all the flagging on your closures by the way (shouldn't be detrimental to you considering your contributions). Fair asker should ping you in comments before flagging. But with the super counter-intuitive way of doing it (typing the name of the hammerer being the only way to contact them), no wonder why some people prefer the "flag" option.

Comment: This is good advice, [where have I heard it before?](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6?m=44784110#44784110) :-) I did the exact same thing when my colleague came out with the [pivot canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe), at that time I did not seem to find any resistance closing duplicates. Suddenly, when the target is my post, it becomes a "conflict of interest" and people automatically have a problem with it. FWIW, I did listen and stop hammering after I was warned previously, but did not realise it would spiral into such an issue.