# What to do about this deleted "canonical" question and its duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, deleted-questions, canonical

While looking at the result of my SEDE query for find [duplicates of deleted questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209965/duplicates-of-deleted-questions), I noticed a rather large number of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions about ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions that were all orphaned when [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568261/how-to-avoid-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-or-indexoutofboundsexception) was deleted by Community ♦ on October 8, 2018.

Based on the [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32568261/timeline), and a bit of searching, here's what I think happened:

- The question was posted and self-answered on September 14, 2015 by a high-rep user with a gold badge in the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag.  (I will not include their name here, as they're no longer active on SO, although it's not particularly hard to dig it up.)  The question itself, from [its first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32568261/1), contained a notice explicitly stating that:

  > This is meant to be the most comprehensive [Canonical](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291994) collection of information on this `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` topic.
- Over time, the author of the question apparently then proceeded to use their gold badge powers to close quite a few other questions as duplicates of it.
- On February 17, 2016, [a meta discussion about the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/is-this-an-acceptable-canonical-question-and-answer-for-a-common-java-exception) was started.  As far as I can tell, the general consensus was that [another, older and highly voted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it) was a better choice for a canonical question on this topic.  Probably as a consequence of this extra attention, the question's score also dropped from +1 / -0 to +2 / -4 in one day.
- The next day, on February 18, 2016, the question was closed by another gold badge holder (who had also participated in the meta discussion) as a duplicate of the previously mentioned older question.  A [reopen review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/11318151) was triggered just a few hours later, but it concluded with a unanimous decision to leave the question closed.  Two more reopen reviews were later also triggered, on [February 26](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/11412476) and [March 22](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/11722431), but both reached the same conclusion.
- While the question remained closed, its original author continued to maintain it, and it continued to receive both up- and downvotes, eventually ending up at +14 / -23.
- On October 8 of this year, the question author's account on Stack Overflow was deleted.  (I do not know the reason for this, and will not speculate, but I do note that they apparently remain active on other Stack Exchange sites.)  This caused all of their negatively scored closed questions, including this particular one, to be [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account/7979#7979).  As the deletion was done by Community ♦, it bypassed the mechanism that normally prevents the deletion of questions with duplicates.

So, at this point, here we are with [134 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/793984/dupetree-find-all-duplicates-of-a-question?PostId=32568261) closed as duplicates of the same "canonical" question, which no longer exists.  My question is, what should we do next?

I can see several possible options:

1. **Undelete it** (but leave it closed).  This would effectively restore things to *status quo ante*, before the auto-deletion of the question in October.  It would also be one of the easiest options, requiring only a small number of high-rep users to vote to undelete.
2. **Undelete it and merge it** with [the question it was closed as a duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it).  This would have the side effect of moving its two answers, including the intended canonical answer by its author, to the established canonical question.  This would require a ♦ moderator to perform the merge, but at least they could easily do all of it alone.
3. Recruit a posse of gold badge holders (and/or ♦ moderators) to **edit all the dupe links** for the 134 "orphaned" questions to point to the established canonical question instead.  This would require more work, but half a dozen users or so should be able to handle it pretty quickly.  Unfortunately, this is not an option I can help with, as I don't have a gold badge in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) (or anywhere else, for that matter; my contributions are spread over too many different tags).
4. **Several of the above**, e.g. merging the question *and* editing the dupe links to point directly to the merge target.
5. **None of the above**, just let it stay deleted.  The problem with this option is that it leaves over a hundred questions with broken duplicate links, unless we spend a considerable amount of effort getting them all deleted (or reopened, or edited to point to another duplicate, which would really be option #3 above).

Unfortunately, none of those options (well, except for the last one) are something I can accomplish on my own.  So, before going to chat or somewhere else to recruit assistance in clearing up this mess, I'd like to ask if the rest of the community has any strong opinions on how this should be best handled.  Personally, I'm rather ambivalent between options #1 to #4 above, perhaps with a slight preference for #2 (or #4).

Comment: #3 can probably best be accomplished by just an SE employee running a script...

Comment: If nothing else this would be a potential bug in how a user who creates a canonical but doesn't *yet* meet the threshold for manual content deletion review could still do a decent amount of damage once their content is deleted with their account.

Comment: @Servy:  From an efficiency standpoint you're right about the mod running a script, but I think a quiet hour or so with two or three other Java badge holders would get the job done...

Comment: @Makoto But then you're filling the active feed with 134 questions, even ignoring the time of the badge holders.

Comment: ...which means that there will be eyes on the questions and appropriate scrutiny given to them.  I'm not seeing a problem @Servy; the people who would ignore Java questions wouldn't be as impacted by this, and the system would be working as intended since edits like this shouldn't be kept hidden.

Comment: @Makoto You really want anyone interested in discussing the issue to participate in this meta discussion (and ideally before it happens).  They don't then need to see the actual edits to every single question filling their feed for hours.

Comment: Analness Alert! - Could you reword #3 so that the bold part is at the start the same as the other options? It's slightly jarring the way it is just now but also feels like that option is being slightly biased. I tried to edit but couldn't so I done the hard work here instead: "3. **Edit all the dupe links** for the 134 "orphaned" questions to point to the established canonical question instead with help from a posse of gold badge holders (and/or ♦ moderators)."

Comment: The question was undeleted on 2019-01-07.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm in favor of a manual approach to handle this, which would be #3.  The reasoning is fairly simple:  there's a lot of content here which should be double-checked to see if there's anything still worth keeping around here as "useful signposts", and if there are, editing them a bit wouldn't be the worst thing to happen to them.

Having a unilateral action to modify the questions' target without much insight into what's doing would mean that we lose the visibility into if those questions were even worth bothering to begin with.

The now-deleted non-canonical is right where it should be and it shouldn't be resurrected.  At best the existing canonical could be reorganized a bit to coalesce and gather all of the info in one answer...but the information is *still* there and having the non-canonical merged into it wouldn't be adding anything new.

Comment: It looks like this is the most popular option. It also looks like some people have probably started doing this already, since there are only 95 [duplicates of the deleted question](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/793984/dupetree-find-all-duplicates-of-a-question?PostId=32568261) left as of the last SEDE update. At this rate, fixing them all shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 6):

I'm in favour of option 2.

The majority of these questions are zero- or negative-scored. I guess we might as well fix the dupe targets, but further editing isn't a worthwhile use of what would probably add up to several man-hours of gold badgers' lives.

[Makoto suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377970/1709587) that if we do anything other than option 3 then *"we lose the visibility into if those questions were even worth bothering to begin with."*. Okay, but what are we actually supposed to do about those that aren't? Gold badgers can't unilaterally delete, so can't do anything with the bad signposts other than a) fix the duplicate target despite the duplicate's worthlessness, or b) deliberately leave the duplicate target broken. Since (a) is clearly preferable, option 3 will end up with the gold badgers fixing all the duplicate targets anyway.

We might as well save them the busywork of sifting through garbage by having a mod fix the whole situation with a single action.

Comment: @Servy Merging (which mods can do) will automagically change the dupe targets, won't it? Even if it doesn't, it'll cause normal users to get redirected to the new canonical when they follow the dupe link. No need for a script.

Answer (score -8):

> 5. None of the above, just let it stay deleted. The problem with this option is that it leaves over a hundred questions with broken duplicate links, unless we spend a considerable amount of effort getting them all deleted (or reopened, or edited to point to another duplicate, which would really be option #3 above).

SO is a site and like everything else in life there are consequences for peoples actions. The author with a 100k+ rep decided to leave the site. He knew what he was doing. Is the outcome unintended and disadvantageous for the rest. Yes very much so.

Still I think he and his posts have to be treated the same way as if someone like me was going to delete his account. Its a matter of fairness and respect to everyone who contributes. My guess is an new "canonical" question will arise and takes its place over time and people will adept.

EDIT: in my original post I overlooked that he couldn't have delete his own question under these conditions. I removed that part. However I learned something new and some of you might have learned something new as well. So down voted answers might still hold value.

Comment: A new canonical already exists.  The issue is that we now have a ton of questions with no useful signpost which may need more moderation attention.  Doing nothing doesn't fix that.

Comment: It would have been impossible for the author of the question to delete the question with both answers and questions marked as a duplicate of it.